# Method of obtaining version with parameter

Tags: java

I am looking for A method of obtaining the version of my project by invoking the main class with a "--version" parameter and have it dump the project version and exit. kind of like if you were to type java -version in the command line.

I understand that I would need something like, but do not understand the implementation of the method.

`private final static String VERSION="0.1.0"`

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?  It does not compute.

Comment: Simply parse the command line arguments and print out the version number. You might want to be more specific about which part you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I do not understand the implementation of the method, I need to be able to easyly type in MYproject -version and have it output the version number just like if I were looking for the verison number of java using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for what I was trying to do.

```
 private final static String VERSION="version: 01.00.0000";
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals(versionArg)){
                System.out.println(VERSION);
                System.exit(0);
            }
```